# change action of 'Save Image As' to redirect to appropriate webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am looking for a way to change the behavior of 'Save Image As' when people try to download the small logo files from my website.  I don't mind them using my logo, but I would prefer that the get the one from my actual downloads page so it is good quality.

Ideally I would like to be able to set a css class up so I can apply the behavior to specific images.  I don't need it to be on every image on the site.

Answer (score 1):

when someone visit your website, images are downloaded and saved in the cache folder.

but you can disable Right Click mouse on your site to prevent people to Save Image:

```
<script>
    document.onmousedown=disableclick;
    status="Right Click Disabled";
    function disableclick(event)
    {
      if(event.button==2)
       {
         alert(status);
         return false;    
       }
    }
</script>
```

but remember people still can access to your logo. but harder.

```js
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
  {
    alert(status);
    return false;    
  }
}
```

```html
<p>some thing</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the right click and ctrl+u etc for preventing your logo to be saved by others. You can put this code on your head part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;

if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler(){
return false;
}

function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=false;
}

document.onkeydown=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=true;
if(((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 117) || (e.which == 65) || (e.which == 97) || (e.which == 67) || (e.which == 99)) && isCtrl == true)
{
// alert(‘Keyboard shortcuts are cool!’);
return false;
}
}
</script>
```